# lapply and subsetting columns

Tags: r, subset, xts, lapply

I would like the make the bit that uses `lapply()` more elegant...(i.e. a one liner would be good) rather than having to set up a function before. i.e. is there a standard function in which i can use `[,c(1:4)]` or something similar as an argument...

so to make a reproducible example...

```
x <- xts(matrix(rnorm(500*8),ncol=8),Sys.Date()-500:1)
x.m <- split(x,'months')
```

The following basically only takes the first 4 columns for each element of the list created from the split and thus i have to make a function that does this but i would like it to be more elegant somehow...

```
ff <- function(xts.obj){xts.obj[,c(1:4)]}

g <- lapply(x.m, ff)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[` is a function

```
> args(xts:::`[.xts`)
function (x, i, j, drop = FALSE, which.i = FALSE, ...) 
NULL
```

So, you can just use that.  Either of these will do it.

```
lapply(x.m, '[', , c(1:4))
lapply(x.m, '[', j=c(1:4))
```

Comment: I'd venture to guess that `lapply(x.m, OHLC)` would also probably work with your real data. ;-)

Comment: hahaha...good guess...how would you use OHLC if you have two ohlc xts objects that were merged together (i.e. side by side)?

Comment: I wouldn't, which is why I just mentioned it in the comments.  `OHLC` won't even work like you want if you have a column named, e.g., OpenInterest

Comment: yeh that's what I thought...just checking that there wasnt some magic trick that managed to do what I needed, all one in one go...Thanks very much though for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

If just having the extra function floating around bugs you, you can use an anonymous function within the `lapply` call.

```
g <- lapply(x.m, FUN = function(x){x[, c(1:4]}
```